# How can I make all cells of a Row have the width of the widest one?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a "ToggleGroup" with Jetpack-Compose, using essentially a `Row` into which I print `Text`. I manage to make it work if I tune the `width` manually (`.width(70.dp)` in the code below), but I would like it to automatically do that.

I essentially want this:

[image]

But without manually adding `.width(70.dp)`, I get this:

[image]

My current (tuned) code is the following:

```kotlin
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
) {
    options.forEach { option ->
        val isSelected = option == selectedOption
        val textColor = if (isSelected) Color.White else MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        val backgroundColor = if (isSelected) Color.Gray else Color.White
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    vertical = 6.dp, horizontal = 1.dp
                )
                .width(70.dp)
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .clickable { onSelectionChanged(option) }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = option,
                color = textColor,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(14.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It feels similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414937/compose-column-that-fill-parent-and-have-all-child-same-width), but somehow it's different because I use `Row` and the question uses `Column` (or at least I did not manage to use `Intrinsics` correctly).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes required.

#### 1. On the parent `Row`, use `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)`

> (min|max)IntrinsicWidth: Given this height, what's the minimum/maximum width you can paint your content properly?

Source - [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements)

#### 2. Use `Modifier.weight(1F)` on all children.

> Size the element's width proportional to its weight relative to other weighted sibling elements in the Row.
>
> The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

Source - [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean))

#### 3. Use `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)` on all children.

This ensures the `Text` inside the children composables are not wrapped.

(You can verify this by removing the modifier and adding long text)

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Sample code**

```
@Composable
fun AutoWidthRow() {
    val items = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 300")
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
        modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
    ) {
        items.forEach { option ->
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        vertical = 6.dp, horizontal = 1.dp
                    )
                    .width(IntrinsicSize.Max) // Removing this will wrap the text
                    .weight(1F)
                    .background(Color.Black)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = option,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(14.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, actually in your code (which works), you don't set `IntrinsicSize.Max` on the children. Is it still necessary?

Comment: @JonasVautherin, Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to update the code. Yes, it is required. You can test what happens by removing this with long text. (The text will be wrapped like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc39A.png))

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom `Layout`

```
@Composable
fun EqualSizeTiles(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        layoutTiles(
            measurables,
            constraints
        )
    }
}

private fun MeasureScope.layoutTiles(
    measurables: List<Measurable>,
    constraints: Constraints,
): MeasureResult {
    val tileHeight = constraints.maxHeight
    val tileWidths = measurables.map { measurable ->
        measurable.maxIntrinsicWidth(tileHeight)
    }
    val tileWidth = tileWidths.maxOrNull() ?: 0
    val tileConstraints = Constraints(
        minWidth = tileWidth,
        minHeight = 0,
        maxWidth = tileWidth,
        maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight,
    )
    val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
        measurable.measure(tileConstraints)
    }
    val width = (placeables.size * tileWidth).coerceAtMost(constraints.maxWidth)
    return layout(width = width, height = tileHeight) {
        placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
            placeable.place(tileWidth * index, 0)
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 512)
@Composable
private fun EqualSizeTilesPreview() {
    WeatherSampleTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            EqualSizeTiles(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(64.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Green)
                    .padding(all = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Left",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.Red)
                        .padding(all = 8.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Center",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                        .padding(all = 8.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                )
                Text(
                    text = "Right element",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = Color.Blue)
                        .padding(all = 8.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```